# Fetching 2000 rows from a table with JOIN on 2 other tables using JPA takes more time

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

For fetching around 2000 rows there were around 4000 SQLs generated by JPA based on the report from **show-sql** enabled on spring boot. But the Time spent in executing this is 4197447657 nanoseconds which is just 4 seconds.

```
INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {_

 131968 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;_
 0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;_
 85800114 nanoseconds spent preparing 4054 JDBC statements;_
 4197447657 nanoseconds spent executing 4054 JDBC statements;_
 0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;_
 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;_
 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;_
 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;_
 30440506604 nanoseconds spent executing 2018 flushes (flushing a total of 4105857 entities and 4091737 collections);_
 4651766 nanoseconds spent executing 2018 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)_}
```

But If I put a log **`System.out.println(System.currentTimeInMillis)`** in Java before and after the DB fetch call it takes around **41177ms**

Any idea why it is happening so and how to overcome this?

***Note***: All the 3 tables are having minimal `BLOB` content in a column.

Comment: If this is  read only operation then you can try marking the transaction as such `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`. That should enable hibernate to skip dirty checking and flushing.

Comment: This is working. Yes it is a read only operation. Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`30440506604 nanoseconds spent executing 2018 flushes (flushing a total of 4105857 entities and 4091737 collections);_`

It seems like you have some flushes operations,but you're not include in your '4197447657 nanoseconds'.

If you enable transcational or acquire a read-write lock, your fetch operation will be block when there have flushes operation.

So,41177 ms contains all the time spring boot shown in the log:

40440506604 + 4651766 + 4197447657 + 85800114 + 131968 = 44728538109 ns = 44728.54 ms.

Comment: Cool. Got it. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: 2000 rows affected 4105857 entitys,if you are using JPA,you should try to guarantee operate objects using JPQL,if you're using both JPQL and SQL ,there will be unpredictable.

Comment: A normal process is: query using jpql -> jpa entity -> operate entity(change property using getXXX and setXXX) -> save entity using entityManager.save().

Comment: Was having a @Transactional inside a method and it caused flushing and hence the slowness.